# How to add the highlighter bar that highlights under the link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a highlight above a link in the status bar (here named progress bar), The highlight should stay above the active link then move above the link that is the mouse is hovering. The fiddle site does this (so do many others, fiddle is just on the top of mind)and the image show an example of what i want to do. Fiddle adds below I would like mine above.

The small blue line under "collaboration":
[image]

```js
           $(function() {

      $("li").on("mouseover mouseleave",
         function () {
          $("#progressbar").toggleClass("highlight"); 

         });

            setInterval("rotateimages()", 1000);
        });


        function rotateimages() {

            var curPhoto = $("#photoShow div.current");
            var nextPhoto = curPhoto.next();
            if (nextPhoto.length == 0) {
                return;
            } 

            curPhoto.removeClass("current").addClass('previous');  
            nextPhoto.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('current').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
                curPhoto.removeClass('previous');
            });         
        }
```

```css
     #logo { float: left; }

     #nav  {
        list-style-type:none; 
        float:right;
    } 
    li {
        display: inline-block;
        border-right: thin;
    } 

    #progressbar{
        float: right;
        background-color: #D2D5D5;
        height: 5px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .highlight {
        background-color: #79CDFE;
    }

    .topnav {
        background-color: #FEFEFE;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .topnav a {
        width:100%;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px; 
    }

    #nav a:hover {
        background-color: white;
        color: #79CDFE;
        background-origin: : #79CDFE;
        border-top: #79CDFE;
    }

    .topnav a.active {
        background-color: white;
        color: #79CDFE;
    }
    .status-menu {
        width: 98px;
        height: 5px;
        background: #4EFFFF;
        position: absolute;
    }

    body {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>


    <div class="topnav">

    <div id="progressbar">
        <div id="care"></div>
        <div id="hospital"></div>
        <div id="service"></div>
        <div id="about"></div>
        <div id="news"></div>
    </div>

        <img src="src/images/logo.png" id="logo" class="gallery"/>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li> <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#care">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#hospital">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#service">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#about">Link 4</a></li>
             <li><a class="" href="#news">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
          
    </div> 
  
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a highlight bar above the link, I think it would be best to use a `::before` pseudo element on the link which you can position anywhere you want. It's currently at the top of the progress bar but it can go higher or lower if needed.

```js
$(function() {

  $("li").on("mouseover mouseleave",
     function () {
      $("#progressbar").toggleClass("highlight");

     });

        setInterval("rotateimages()", 1000);
    });


    function rotateimages() {

        var curPhoto = $("#photoShow div.current");
        var nextPhoto = curPhoto.next();
        if (nextPhoto.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        curPhoto.removeClass("current").addClass('previous');
        nextPhoto.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('current').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            curPhoto.removeClass('previous');
        });
    }
```

```css
#logo { float: left; }

#nav  {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:right;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: thin;
}

#progressbar{
    float: right;
    background-color: #D2D5D5;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.highlight {
    background-color: #79CDFE;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #FEFEFE;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
}

.topnav a::before {
    background-color: transparent;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -21px;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #79CDFE;
    background-origin: #79CDFE;
}

#nav a:hover::before {
    background-color: #79CDFE;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: white;
    color: #79CDFE;
}

.topnav a.active::before {
    background-color: #79CDFE;
}

.status-menu {
    width: 98px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #4EFFFF;
    position: absolute;
}

body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>


    <div class="topnav">

    <div id="progressbar">
        <div id="care"></div>
        <div id="hospital"></div>
        <div id="service"></div>
        <div id="about"></div>
        <div id="news"></div>
    </div>

        <img src="src/images/logo.png" id="logo" class="gallery"/>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li> <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#care">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#hospital">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#service">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#about">Link 4</a></li>
             <li><a class="" href="#news">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    </header>
```

Comment: This has the desired effect but it does not go into the fore mentioned status bar (named here progress bar).

Comment: I'm still trying to fully understand what it is you're looking for. What I showed you is just like on JSFiddle but on top. Did you want the highlight above the progress bar? Just how it is just above the bar? I'll update my answer then with that.

Comment: Did you want the highlight to be on top of the progress bar or above? If it's above then I would need to move the progress bar down a bit to make room for the link highlight.

Comment: It should be on top of the progress bar, and using your solution i managed to have the same effect i was looking for, by first giving the `ul` tag a negative margin, and then another `border-top` on the navigation bar, so I' not using the progress bar, its not perfect but it does the trick.